# If the Laplace transforms of two functions are equal, are the functions equal?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

In other words, is the following true?
$$\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\, dt=\int_0^\infty g(t)e^{-st}\, dt\implies f(t)=g(t)$$

If not, what are examples of different functions with the same Laplace transforms (other than those that differ by a constant)?

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/jorloff/www/18.03-esg/notes/extra/laplaceuniqueness.pdf

Comment: I have (hopefully) improved the question and wonder if it can be reopened in its current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take

$$f(t)=0$$

and

$$g(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & t=1 \\ 0 & t\neq 1 \\ \end{cases}$$
They are different functions with the same Laplace transform.